# What's the error in this simulated amplifier circuit?

Tags: amplifier, simulation

I have attempted to simulate (using [Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/)) an IC amplifier circuit (the LM386-3) based on the schematic [reference manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm386.pdf). Here is the schematic:

[image: LM386 Schematic]

and here is my simulated version:

[image: LM386 Simulation]

On the bottom left is the +-400mV input voltage (the 40Hz AC source on the left). In the bottom middle is the output voltage (measured at the output point on the right-hand side). As you can see, the output is not exactly what you might expect from an amplifier. The only difference I can see from the reference diagram is the capacitor and resistor at the two gain terminals but I get a similar output if I remove them. What could be causing the strange stepped output that I am seeing?

You can run the simulation here: http://goo.gl/HNkOfp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Zener diode where you should have a current regulator (shown as an arrow inside a circle). As a result the upper output transistor cannot pull up to the supply voltage, so the output waveform has low amplitude and is distorted.

Try replacing the Zener with a current mirror set to about 4mA, like this:-

[image]

(the LM386 probably uses a FET to create a constant current source, but the circuit above should be close enough for working at 5V).

Response to edit:

Now that you have changed the Zener to a current source, the circuit is doing what it should! The 'stepped' output is simply due to over-driving the amplifier. With 400mV input and gain =20 it wants to output 8V, but only 5V is available so it hits the supply rails first.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that myself just now and I've updated the screenshot to show the result with a current source of 25uA and I still get a stepped output. With a higher current than that, the output remains pretty much the same (less than than drops the voltage to below 5).

Comment: That's a lot better, it's now doing what it should! Only possible issue is that 250uA may not be enough when driving a low impedance load.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. In my circuit there is a connection between the two diodes to the output wire. In the schematic, there is not! I will update if I can but right now, if I try to make that change, the simulator hangs!

Comment: Thanks! Making that change and then lowering the input voltage from 400mV to 40mV gives a nice smooth sine wave between 1.8V and 4.8V.